# can't import @nota/nativescript-webview-ext/vue in nativescript vue

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

i tryed to import the Nota NativeScript Webview Ext in my nativescript vue application (see https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/@nota%2Fnativescript-webview-ext)

i added the npm package in the playground web application without any errors or problems.

the following code is used in my app.js file:

```
import Vue from 'nativescript-vue';
import App from './components/App';

import '@nota/nativescript-webview-ext/vue';

Vue.config.silent = false;

new Vue({
    render: h => h('frame', [h(App)])
}).$start();
```

but unfortunately i got the following error

```
2019-06-11 15:55:30.942 nsplaydev[15435:3295521] PlayLiveSync: Uncaught Exception
2019-06-11 15:55:30.942 nsplaydev[15435:3295521] *** JavaScript call stack:
(

)
2019-06-11 15:55:30.942 nsplaydev[15435:3295521] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NativeScript encountered a fatal error: Error: Could not find module '@nota/nativescript-webview-ext/vue'. Computed path '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F4AE564B-FAFA-4128-BC98-F087145C5FF1/Documents/Playground/LiveSync/app/tns_modules/@nota/nativescript-webview-ext/vue'.
at 
1 require@file:///app/app.js:11:8
2 anonymous@file:///app/app.js:11:8
3 evaluate@[native code]
4 moduleEvaluation@[native code]
5 promiseReactionJob@[native code]
', reason: '(null)'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1ba9623a8 0x1b9b67d00 0x10499f7f4 0x1049dda00 0x1059433c8 0x10429b3f0 0x1ba3a8fd8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
2019-06-11 15:55:30.942 nsplaydev[15435:3295521] PlayLiveSync: Uncaught Exception
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all the plugins are supported in Playground, only plugins without native dependencies are supported.

`nativescript-webview-ext` has native dependency for both iOS & Android, so it might not work as intended on Playground / Preview app.

**FYI:** Even if you use a plugin without native dependency, while running with Playground / Preview app, you should use relative path for importing anything from plugin.

Comment: Hello Manoj. Thank you very much for your answer! Does this mean that the problem is caused by playground? Would another development environment solve my problem? If so, which alternative development environment can I use to solve this?

Comment: We can't call it a problem, but it's more of a limitation. You can run the app locally with all SDK setup, that should work.